# IEEEeqnarray + Hyperref -> reference jumps to the beginning of the document

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, ieeetran

This is a problem concerning `\IEEEeqnarray`, `\IEEEyessubnumber`, and `\eqref` in combination with `hyperref.sty`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
page1\newpage
\phantomsection\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
\IEEEyesnumber\label{eqn} \IEEEyessubnumber*
  a &=&b \label{subeqn}\\
    &=&c
\end{IEEEeqnarray} 
clicking \eqref{subeqn} sends me to the correct position :)\\
clicking \eqref{eqn} sends me to the beginning of the document :(
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Problem** 
Clicking on (1) sends me to the beginning of the document, instead of to Equation (1).

---

**Related questions**
["IEEEeqnarray vs. hyperref -> reference jumps to the beginning of the section
"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41280/ieeeeqnarray-vs-hyperref-reference-jumps-to-the-beginning-of-the-section) 
 I think it is not a duplicate as the solution therein, namely adding `\phantomsection` as in the MWE, has no effect.

**Additional Information** 
I use IEEEtrantools 2015/08/26 V1.5 by Michael Shell.

---

Comment: what is so special on `IEEEeqnarray`, that you use it? you load `amsmath` and with it you can use `align` inside `subequations` and all will work as expected ...

Comment: this document even more convinced me, that  `amsmath` environments are superior to result of the  `IEEEeqnarray`. however, with way as i suggested you before, links will work as expected.

Comment: @Zarko see Section 4.1
moser-isi.ethz.ch/docs/typeset_equations.pdf
I'd prefer if we leave it to that instead of trailing off topic ;)

Comment: Sorry, but I couldn't agree less with the reference you link. The fact that the author suggests using some sort of `\hspace` which (I quote) "will never yield a precise arrangement" simply means the author does not know how to use `align`.

Comment: @campa
Point taken (at least on the first glance). I'll go with `IEEEeqnarray` anyway, as I'm working on a 200+ page document that already uses it. Thanks for insisting on Zarko's point though, I'll consider switching to `align` for the next project.

Comment: Don't misunderstand me, I have nothing against `IEEE`. It seems a valid alternative. But _all_ alleged flaws of `amsmath` are just ignorance of the author. Which syntax is more convenient might well be a matter of taste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IEEEeqnaray uses `\stepcounter{equation}` instead of `\refstecounter{equation}`, then sets `\@currentlabel` and `\@currentHref` directly. `\IEEEyesnumber` just sets a flag for later use.

The group containing `\label{eqn}` can be inserted almost anywhere.  It is a sort of `\pseudoequation` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
page1\newpage

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
{\addtocounter{equation}{-1}\refstepcounter{equation}\label{eqn}}%
\IEEEyesnumber\IEEEyessubnumber*
  a &=&b \label{subeqn}\\
    &=&c
\end{IEEEeqnarray} 
clicking \eqref{subeqn} sends me to the correct position :)\\
clicking \eqref{eqn} sends me to the beginning of the document :(
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you John - it works!

I've saved myself some adaption time by just redefining \IEEEeqnarray accordingly, i.e., I add to the preamble

    `\let\oldIEEEyesnumber\IEEEyesnumber`
    `\renewcommand{\IEEEyesnumber}[0]{{\addtocounter{equation}{-1}\refstepcounter{equation}}\oldIEEEyesnumber}`

Comment: The \label has to be inside the group with the \refstepcounter.  I deliberately used local changes so as not to interfere with the subequation numbering.  Try creating a \eqnlabel command instead.

Comment: Thank you again John! `\newcommand{\eqlabel}[1]{\addtocounter{equation}{-1}\refstepcounter{equation}\label{#1}}`